# two or more dots in a django template after the variable

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In a django template, is it possible to have two (or more) dots after a variable?  For example, say I have a list of objects that I first want to use a list-index lookup for and then once I have the object, I want to call its method for getting the absolute url, should that work?

```
For example:
    {% for entry in myList %}
    {{ entry.0.get_absolute_url }}
    {% endfor %}
```

So the 0 is asking for the first item in the list which is an object, then I want to get the absolute url.  It doesn't work when I try it but it doesn't return an error either.  Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

To clarify it, what's strange is that:

This works:

```
{{ singleObject.get_absolute_url }}
```

In that case if I just try `{{ singleObject }}`, I get the unicode value of that object so something like: `John Smith`

This doesn't work:

```
{% for object in objectList %}
{{ object.get_absolute_url }}
{% endfor %}
```

But in this case, if I put in {{ object }}, I no longer get the unicode value.  I get: `[<Name: John Smith>]`  (name being the name of the model)

Basically, the method works when it's outside of a loop.  Could there be any reason for that?

Comment: more than one dot absolutely works, is `entry` a list? or is `myList` the list?

Comment: Django won't return errors for templates, it squashes them all always.  Its quite annoying : ).

Comment: @MattoTodd I bet you figured it out, maybe you should post that as an answer?

Comment: @MattoTodd:  Well, actually myList is a list of lists so entry.0 would be the first item in each list of myList.  Sorry for the confusion

Comment: If you want to know why it's not working for you, you'll need to include more information, and actually make that part of your question :)

Comment: @bradley.ayers: okay, updated my question with some more info

Comment: @sq1020 my next question would be: how are you building your list (do you know the list is making it into the template ok?)

Comment: @sq1020 show us the relevant code from the view :)

Comment: @MattoTodd: okay, I added some more code that I think could help crack this.  The list is being built but it seems to be returning the actual object which shouldn't be a problem I would guess

Comment: @sq1020 if `{{ singleObject }}` and `{{ object }}` are returning different objects (or printing out different outputs) then they are obviously different objects. c'mon buddy sack up and show us the view where you are querying for this list vs. the single item. there must be something different between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.  I had brackets around each item in my list like so:

```
objectList = [['John Smith'], ['Jim Jones'], ['Bill White']]
```

Silly me!  Thanks so much for your all your input

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is perfectly acceptable in Django templates. There is no better way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

more than one dot absolutely works.

based on your comment,  there is no `entry.0` because `entry` IS the first item in the list cause you are already looping through `myList'

just use `entry.get_absolute_url` instead

but if you only want to print out the url for the first entry, forgo the for loop and just use `myList.0.get_absolute_url`

UPDATE:

there's a tip from 'the pragmatic programmer' that says:

> ``select’’ Isn’t Broken
>
> It is rare to find a bug in the OS or the
>   compiler, or even a third-party product or library. The bug is most
>   likely in the application.

i think you assumed that django templates were behaving weird, when the truth is you were not building your list correctly.  don't be afraid to show some of your actual code,  by abstracting the problem for us, you removed the part that included the problem

Comment: is there any reason why a method would not work for any object inside a django template loop but the same method would work for an individual object outside the loop?  I find it rather strange but that's what is happening!

Comment: it may seem that way, but there is probably some difference. you have yet to say what your real intention is (print the first entry's url, or print all entry urls). either edit your post with actual code so a second set of eyes can look at it,  or walk through your code talking yourself through it OUTLOUD and i'd be willing to bet good money somethings not lining up along the way. happens to the best of us......the computer is behaving exactly is it's supposed to

Comment: I finally got it.  The view was a little convoluted so I was hesitant to put it up.  Thanks a lot anyway!